# Why can't I adjust parameters of wood texture of my deform modifier?

Tags: modifiers

Hi I play with the default textures of the displace modifier, and I found one that I like, but I need to change the distance of the rings in the wood texture. Why are the parameters greyed out? How can I adjust it?

[image]